# Migration Chrome Extension v3 Notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications, migration, manifest

I am trying to migrate my Google Chrome extension manifest v2 to v3.
But I have an error when I try to create a notification.

Error in service worker:

```
extensions::imageUtil:11
Uncaught ReferenceError: Image is not defined
at loadImageData (extensions::imageUtil:11)
at Object.loadAllImages (extensions::imageUtil:74)
at replaceNotificationOptionURLs (extensions::notifications:89)
at extensions::notifications:115
at service_workers.js:2
```

My service_workers.js:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    chrome.notifications.create({
        type:     'basic',
        iconUrl:  'assets/images/icon_128.png',
        title:    'MyTitle',
        message:  'MyMessage!'
    });
});
```

My manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "My Extension",
 "description": "...",
 "version": "0.1",
 "manifest_version": 3,
 "permissions": [
   "storage",
   "alarms",
   "notifications",
   "activeTab",
   "tabs"
 ],
 "host_permissions": [
   "http://localhost:3000/api/data"
 ],
 "background": {
   "service_worker": "service_workers.js"
 },
 "action": {
   "default_title": "ExtensionPopup",
   "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
 },
 "icons": {
   "128": "assets/images/icon_128.png"
 },
 "content_security_policy": {
   "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self' "
 }
}
```

I also tried to provide iconUrl with chrome.runtime.getURL or base64 data, with no success.
I am testing on Chrome canary V89.

Am I missing something ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: ManifestV3 still has a lot of bugs, it's too early to use it in production. You can report the bug on https://crbug.com if there isn't an existing report.

Answer (score 6):

according to the document from [devlin@chromium.org for Manifest V3](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nPu6Wy4LWR66EFLeYInl3NzzhHzc-qnk4w4PX-0XMw8/edit#).
[Extension notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) are replaced by [web notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

My notification works like this, but I don't know if that's the right approach:

```
registration.showNotification(title, {
    body: message,
    data: UUID,
    icon: logoUrl,
    message,
    actions: [
      { action: 'Open', title: 'Open' },
      { action: 'Close', title: 'Close' }
    ]
  })

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  if (event.action === 'Open') {
    // something(event.notification.data) // UUID
  }
  event.notification.close()
})
```

Comment: Interesting, that works for me too. I gather since [mv3 documentation describes notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/richNotifications/#develop) that they will fix the bug described in [#1168477](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168477&q=image%20is%20not%20defined%20notification%20manifest%20v3&can=2)

Comment: Wow, who worked on v3? It's horrendous. Thanks