# Google Chrome Extensions v3 - Error in event handler: ReferenceError: Image is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to create a chrome extension with Manifest v3.
When creating a notification i need to set an iconUrl. The icon is "48.png" and it is with the manifest.json in the root folder.

Instead of my notification i get an error:

```
Error in event handler: ReferenceError: Image is not defined
```

In v3 they changed the web_accessable_resources definition. I think im setting it wrong but it could also be something else..

My Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description":
  "Shows off desktop notifications, which are \"toast\" windows that pop up on the desktop.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {"16": "16.png", "48": "48.png", "128": "128.png"},
  "permissions": ["alarms","storage", "notifications"],
  "background": {"service_worker": "background.js"},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["48.png"],
    "matches": [],
    "extension_ids": [],
    "use_dynamic_url": false
  }]
}
```

My background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    var options = {
        title: "Title",
        message: "Message goes here",
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: "48.png"
    };

    return chrome.notifications.create("", options, function() {});
});
```

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome. ManifestV3 is still in early development, it's not ready.

Comment: BTW web_accessible_resources isn't needed to display icons in notifications. As a workaround you can use a [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) for your image.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the answer! data URI ist throwing the same error. Would you suggest using v2 till v3 is more stable?

Comment: Yep, I don't see any other solution.

Comment: It looks like [#1168477](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168477&q=image%20is%20not%20defined%20notification%20manifest%20v3&can=2) is the relevant bug. I thought Manifest v3 was ready with Chrome 88 but apparently that announcement jumped the gun.

Comment: P.S. @spddl shared a way to do notifications with service workers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65824854/2636364)